# Mirror pc display to the raspberry pi

Tags: raspbian

I'm trying to find a way to game in my room's TV and simply playing the game on my pc and viewing it on my tv is the way I think of. But the problem is that my pc can't connect to the TV in any way so I thought of connecting my Pi to the TV and mirroring my PC's display to it. But I simply don't know how to do it. 
I'm on Raspbian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply run the game in a VNC session and connect to VNC from the Pi. You'll need a fast network connection, but it should be able to manage without too much of a lag.

You'll need a VNC server on your gaming computer. TightVNC seems to be popular on Windows.

On the Pi, try the solution proposed in [this thread](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=41845):

> Hi everybody!. It worked for me, but I tried a different option: SSVNC:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install ssvnc
> ```
>
> Then I run in the command line : `ssvnc`
>
> It pop up a window where you can enter the session info and change some configuration. It has a lot of different options that worked really good for me, you can even save different session with its configurations. If you run on full screen by pressing F8, you can access to the options and the change scale, color-depth, etc.
>   In my opinion it is really good vnc client.